# How to list security groups for the specific instance via CLI?

Tags: security, aws-cli

I'm looking for syntax like:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --instance-id i-0xyz
```

however, the above sub-command doesn't support `--instance-id` parameter.

I've checked and there are `--filters` and `--query` parameters, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

What would be the easiest way to display the description of the security group of the instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `aws ec2 describe-instances` instead, you can specify the id `--instance-ids <value>` and it will output the security group.

Answer (score 5):

The following one-liner in shell works for me:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids $(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $id --query "Reservations[].Instances[].SecurityGroups[].GroupId[]" --output text) --output text
```

Where `$id` is my instance-id.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids (your Instance id) --query "Reservations[].Instances[].SecurityGroups[].GroupId[]" --output text
```

replace

```
(your instance id)
```

with the specific instance id you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Even better check this out:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output=json | jq '.Reservations[] | .Instances[] | {PrivateAddress: .PrivateIpAddress, Tags: .Tags, KeyName: .KeyName, Tags: .Tags, RunningState: .State, InstanceId: .InstanceId, SecurityGroups: .SecurityGroups}'
```

You don't need to know anything this way ... but you need to install `jq`, to chomp the JSON o/p just right.

A lot of the elements there could be removed I guess ... tags, key names, running state, etc.

Comment: This looks promising, but for me it yields only `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 13`.  I suspect there is some "unanticipated" line in my cli output.

Comment: (I amend my comment, above): I had configured my .aws/config file to output text rather than the default JSON.  So in my case, using `--output=json` on the command line caused the prescribed invocation to operate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this on an EC2 instance and find out its own security groups, you can do:

```shell
id=$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

for sg in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $id \
  --query "Reservations[].Instances[].SecurityGroups[].GroupId[]" \
  --output text)
do
 echo
 aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id $sg --output text
done
```